# Get Group Id Using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest

I want to get group id in single call. I am using below URL

```
<Sitename>/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('Approvers')
```

it is returning object. I want to apply filter to above url to get group id.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your're working with REST you can apend `$select` tag to get specific properties. If would look like like this:

```
<Sitename>/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('Approvers')?$select=id
```

But even in this case you will get object containing at least `__metadata` tag, because SharePoint REST services is based on `OData` web protocol standards specification and works this way.

Comment: Refer [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_GroupCollectionOData) to see the OData representation of Groups and this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx) to know how to get specific properties.

Answer (score 4):

Get all groups of site

```
_api/web/sitegroups
```

Get All Users in Site

```
_api/web/siteusers
```

**Get particular group in site**

```
_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetById(IdOfGroup)
```

Remove particular user from group

```
executor.executeAsync({
  url: "<app web url>/_api/web/sitegroups(GroupId)/users/getbyid(UserId)",
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE" },
  success: successEventHandler,
  error: errorEventHandler
 });
```

Source: [Link](https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/53/)